# Image Data generating for data augmentation

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tf.keras, transfer-learning, data-augmentation

I am working on image classification by transfer learning in the 12 several classes of the dataset. However, I am facing overfitting. As a result, I applied data augmentation (Maybe flying) for recovering the overfitting but that unable to increasing the images. Therefore, İ want to increase the training dataset that will be helped to sort out the overfitting process. How may I increase train data by applying data augmentation methods?

My code:

```
#Data augmentation 

def create_gen():
    # Load the Images with a generator and Data Augmentation
    train_generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
        preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input,
        validation_split=0.1
    )


    test_generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
        preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input
    )

    train_images = train_generator.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe=train_df,
        x_col='Filepath',
        y_col='Label',
        target_size=(224, 224),
        color_mode='rgb',
        class_mode='categorical',
        batch_size=32,
        shuffle=True,
        seed=0,
        subset='training',
        rotation_range=30, # Uncomment to use data augmentation
        zoom_range=0.15,
        width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        shear_range=0.15,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        fill_mode="nearest"
    )

    val_images = train_generator.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe=train_df,
        x_col='Filepath',
        y_col='Label',
        target_size=(224, 224),
        color_mode='rgb',
        class_mode='categorical',
        batch_size=32,
        shuffle=True,
        seed=0,
        subset='validation',
        rotation_range=30, # Uncomment to use data augmentation
        zoom_range=0.15,
        width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        shear_range=0.15,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        fill_mode="nearest"
    )

    test_images = test_generator.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe=test_df,
        x_col='Filepath',
        y_col='Label',
        target_size=(224, 224),
        color_mode='rgb',
        class_mode='categorical',
        batch_size=32,
        shuffle=False
    )
    
    return train_generator,test_generator,train_images,val_images,test_images

# Separate in train and test data
train_df, test_df = train_test_split(image_df, train_size=0.9, shuffle=True, random_state=1)

# Create the generators
train_generator,test_generator,train_images,val_images,test_images = create_gen()

Found 4487 validated image filenames belonging to 12 classes.
Found 498 validated image filenames belonging to 12 classes.
Found 554 validated image filenames belonging to 12 classes.

from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
vggmodel = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=True)

vggmodel.trainable = False

for layers in (vggmodel.layers)[:32][:64] [:128]:
    print(layers)
    layers.trainable = False

<tensorflow.python.keras.engine.input_layer.InputLayer object at 0x7f4ca42fa990>
<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f4ca431cb10>
<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f4ca44bff10>
<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.pooling.MaxPooling2D object at 0x7f4ca43ee350>
<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f4ca43f84d0>
<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f4ca43f80d0>
<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.pooling.MaxPooling2D object at 0x7f4ca43ff3d0>
<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f4ca4402b50>
<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f4ca4405810>
<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f4ca43faf50>
<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.pooling.MaxPooling2D object at 0x7f4ca440a250>
<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f4ca4415490>
<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f4ca440e750>
<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f4ca4419d10>
<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.pooling.MaxPooling2D object at 0x7f4ca4426210>
<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f4ca4421950>
<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f4ca440a8d0>
<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f4ca442cdd0>
<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.pooling.MaxPooling2D object at 0x7f4ca443de50>
<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Flatten object at 0x7f4ca442bc10>
<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x7f4ca4419790>
<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x7f4ca4442850>
<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x7f4ca4349b90>

X= vggmodel.layers[-2].output
X=tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(X)
X = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(X)
predictions = Dense(12, activation="softmax")(X)

model_final = Model(vggmodel.input, predictions)

model_final.compile(optimizer = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=["accuracy"])

from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("vgg16_1.h5", monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=False, period=1)

rlronp=tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau( monitor="val_loss", factor=0.0001,patience=1, verbose=1)

History = model_final.fit(train_images,validation_data=val_images,batch_size = 128,epochs=100,  
callbacks=[tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',patience=95,restore_best_weights=True), ])
tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepaths, monitor='val_loss', verbose=0, save_best_only=False,save_weights_only=False, mode='auto', save_freq='epoch')
model_final.save_weights("vgg16_1.h5")

Epoch 1/100
141/141 [==============================] - 83s 336ms/step - loss: 2.2095 - accuracy: 0.2657 - val_loss: 1.5387 - val_accuracy: 0.4940
Epoch 2/100
141/141 [==============================] - 44s 311ms/step - loss: 1.5197 - accuracy: 0.4756 - val_loss: 1.2171 - val_accuracy: 0.6245
Epoch 3/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 297ms/step - loss: 1.2546 - accuracy: 0.5647 - val_loss: 1.0667 - val_accuracy: 0.6767
Epoch 4/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 297ms/step - loss: 1.0892 - accuracy: 0.6305 - val_loss: 0.9662 - val_accuracy: 0.6647
Epoch 5/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 297ms/step - loss: 0.9737 - accuracy: 0.6766 - val_loss: 0.8760 - val_accuracy: 0.7229
Epoch 6/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 297ms/step - loss: 0.9152 - accuracy: 0.6893 - val_loss: 0.8263 - val_accuracy: 0.7470
Epoch 7/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 298ms/step - loss: 0.8449 - accuracy: 0.7176 - val_loss: 0.7910 - val_accuracy: 0.7490
Epoch 8/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 299ms/step - loss: 0.7915 - accuracy: 0.7372 - val_loss: 0.7395 - val_accuracy: 0.7691
Epoch 9/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 298ms/step - loss: 0.7432 - accuracy: 0.7475 - val_loss: 0.7303 - val_accuracy: 0.7671
Epoch 10/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 296ms/step - loss: 0.7045 - accuracy: 0.7642 - val_loss: 0.6922 - val_accuracy: 0.7791
Epoch 11/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 296ms/step - loss: 0.6728 - accuracy: 0.7696 - val_loss: 0.6956 - val_accuracy: 0.7691
Epoch 12/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 300ms/step - loss: 0.6452 - accuracy: 0.7820 - val_loss: 0.6599 - val_accuracy: 0.7871
Epoch 13/100
141/141 [==============================] - 43s 306ms/step - loss: 0.6231 - accuracy: 0.7947 - val_loss: 0.6561 - val_accuracy: 0.7731
Epoch 14/100
141/141 [==============================] - 43s 301ms/step - loss: 0.6051 - accuracy: 0.7983 - val_loss: 0.6479 - val_accuracy: 0.7811
Epoch 15/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 296ms/step - loss: 0.5797 - accuracy: 0.8068 - val_loss: 0.6187 - val_accuracy: 0.7912
Epoch 16/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 300ms/step - loss: 0.5578 - accuracy: 0.8164 - val_loss: 0.6147 - val_accuracy: 0.8052
Epoch 17/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 299ms/step - loss: 0.5345 - accuracy: 0.8237 - val_loss: 0.6103 - val_accuracy: 0.8012
Epoch 18/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 296ms/step - loss: 0.5260 - accuracy: 0.8224 - val_loss: 0.5988 - val_accuracy: 0.7992
Epoch 19/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 295ms/step - loss: 0.4993 - accuracy: 0.8393 - val_loss: 0.5889 - val_accuracy: 0.7952
Epoch 20/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 297ms/step - loss: 0.4893 - accuracy: 0.8393 - val_loss: 0.5837 - val_accuracy: 0.8012
Epoch 21/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 297ms/step - loss: 0.4738 - accuracy: 0.8451 - val_loss: 0.5698 - val_accuracy: 0.8112
Epoch 22/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 298ms/step - loss: 0.4640 - accuracy: 0.8471 - val_loss: 0.5664 - val_accuracy: 0.8133
Epoch 23/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 297ms/step - loss: 0.4502 - accuracy: 0.8549 - val_loss: 0.5796 - val_accuracy: 0.7992
Epoch 24/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 297ms/step - loss: 0.4349 - accuracy: 0.8580 - val_loss: 0.5452 - val_accuracy: 0.8233
Epoch 25/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 298ms/step - loss: 0.4311 - accuracy: 0.8625 - val_loss: 0.5424 - val_accuracy: 0.8193
Epoch 26/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 297ms/step - loss: 0.4188 - accuracy: 0.8656 - val_loss: 0.5515 - val_accuracy: 0.8253
Epoch 27/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 297ms/step - loss: 0.4119 - accuracy: 0.8638 - val_loss: 0.5458 - val_accuracy: 0.8253
Epoch 28/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 296ms/step - loss: 0.3960 - accuracy: 0.8745 - val_loss: 0.5432 - val_accuracy: 0.8153
Epoch 29/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 297ms/step - loss: 0.3879 - accuracy: 0.8732 - val_loss: 0.5385 - val_accuracy: 0.8233
Epoch 30/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 297ms/step - loss: 0.3814 - accuracy: 0.8785 - val_loss: 0.5346 - val_accuracy: 0.8273
Epoch 31/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 299ms/step - loss: 0.3691 - accuracy: 0.8797 - val_loss: 0.5477 - val_accuracy: 0.8112
Epoch 32/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 295ms/step - loss: 0.3619 - accuracy: 0.8906 - val_loss: 0.5144 - val_accuracy: 0.8333
Epoch 33/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 299ms/step - loss: 0.3608 - accuracy: 0.8859 - val_loss: 0.5221 - val_accuracy: 0.8273
Epoch 34/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 298ms/step - loss: 0.3508 - accuracy: 0.8890 - val_loss: 0.5380 - val_accuracy: 0.8173
Epoch 35/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 297ms/step - loss: 0.3465 - accuracy: 0.8892 - val_loss: 0.5191 - val_accuracy: 0.8333
Epoch 36/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 298ms/step - loss: 0.3375 - accuracy: 0.8961 - val_loss: 0.5168 - val_accuracy: 0.8193
Epoch 37/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 299ms/step - loss: 0.3245 - accuracy: 0.8950 - val_loss: 0.5260 - val_accuracy: 0.8173
Epoch 38/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 299ms/step - loss: 0.3209 - accuracy: 0.9019 - val_loss: 0.5117 - val_accuracy: 0.8293
Epoch 39/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 298ms/step - loss: 0.3201 - accuracy: 0.8999 - val_loss: 0.5051 - val_accuracy: 0.8394
Epoch 40/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 297ms/step - loss: 0.3090 - accuracy: 0.9062 - val_loss: 0.5066 - val_accuracy: 0.8293
Epoch 41/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 297ms/step - loss: 0.3050 - accuracy: 0.9073 - val_loss: 0.5066 - val_accuracy: 0.8373
Epoch 42/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 296ms/step - loss: 0.2995 - accuracy: 0.9042 - val_loss: 0.4944 - val_accuracy: 0.8494
Epoch 43/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 298ms/step - loss: 0.2843 - accuracy: 0.9213 - val_loss: 0.5070 - val_accuracy: 0.8193
Epoch 44/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 296ms/step - loss: 0.2853 - accuracy: 0.9131 - val_loss: 0.4886 - val_accuracy: 0.8313
Epoch 45/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 297ms/step - loss: 0.2836 - accuracy: 0.9131 - val_loss: 0.5081 - val_accuracy: 0.8213
Epoch 46/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 296ms/step - loss: 0.2779 - accuracy: 0.9144 - val_loss: 0.5000 - val_accuracy: 0.8233
Epoch 47/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 296ms/step - loss: 0.2705 - accuracy: 0.9175 - val_loss: 0.4985 - val_accuracy: 0.8193
Epoch 48/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 298ms/step - loss: 0.2592 - accuracy: 0.9213 - val_loss: 0.4903 - val_accuracy: 0.8293
Epoch 49/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 298ms/step - loss: 0.2550 - accuracy: 0.9256 - val_loss: 0.4992 - val_accuracy: 0.8253
Epoch 50/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 297ms/step - loss: 0.2589 - accuracy: 0.9229 - val_loss: 0.4936 - val_accuracy: 0.8373
Epoch 51/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 298ms/step - loss: 0.2536 - accuracy: 0.9276 - val_loss: 0.4827 - val_accuracy: 0.8313
Epoch 52/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 296ms/step - loss: 0.2478 - accuracy: 0.9262 - val_loss: 0.4888 - val_accuracy: 0.8373
Epoch 53/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 297ms/step - loss: 0.2460 - accuracy: 0.9273 - val_loss: 0.4997 - val_accuracy: 0.8273
Epoch 54/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 300ms/step - loss: 0.2343 - accuracy: 0.9314 - val_loss: 0.4892 - val_accuracy: 0.8313
Epoch 55/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 297ms/step - loss: 0.2412 - accuracy: 0.9280 - val_loss: 0.4761 - val_accuracy: 0.8394
Epoch 56/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 297ms/step - loss: 0.2434 - accuracy: 0.9278 - val_loss: 0.4905 - val_accuracy: 0.8474
Epoch 57/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 297ms/step - loss: 0.2305 - accuracy: 0.9340 - val_loss: 0.4950 - val_accuracy: 0.8253
Epoch 58/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 297ms/step - loss: 0.2275 - accuracy: 0.9334 - val_loss: 0.4738 - val_accuracy: 0.8394
Epoch 59/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 298ms/step - loss: 0.2257 - accuracy: 0.9354 - val_loss: 0.4701 - val_accuracy: 0.8514
Epoch 60/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 297ms/step - loss: 0.2177 - accuracy: 0.9349 - val_loss: 0.4792 - val_accuracy: 0.8414
Epoch 61/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 297ms/step - loss: 0.2160 - accuracy: 0.9418 - val_loss: 0.4835 - val_accuracy: 0.8373
Epoch 62/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 297ms/step - loss: 0.2152 - accuracy: 0.9383 - val_loss: 0.4717 - val_accuracy: 0.8394
Epoch 63/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 297ms/step - loss: 0.2103 - accuracy: 0.9423 - val_loss: 0.4933 - val_accuracy: 0.8313
Epoch 64/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 297ms/step - loss: 0.2105 - accuracy: 0.9403 - val_loss: 0.4813 - val_accuracy: 0.8414
Epoch 65/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 297ms/step - loss: 0.2066 - accuracy: 0.9434 - val_loss: 0.4826 - val_accuracy: 0.8373
Epoch 66/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 296ms/step - loss: 0.2002 - accuracy: 0.9454 - val_loss: 0.4675 - val_accuracy: 0.8454
Epoch 67/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 297ms/step - loss: 0.1970 - accuracy: 0.9478 - val_loss: 0.4903 - val_accuracy: 0.8313
Epoch 68/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 296ms/step - loss: 0.1937 - accuracy: 0.9496 - val_loss: 0.4785 - val_accuracy: 0.8333
Epoch 69/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 297ms/step - loss: 0.1969 - accuracy: 0.9494 - val_loss: 0.4741 - val_accuracy: 0.8434
Epoch 70/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 297ms/step - loss: 0.1912 - accuracy: 0.9499 - val_loss: 0.4890 - val_accuracy: 0.8333
Epoch 71/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 296ms/step - loss: 0.1969 - accuracy: 0.9456 - val_loss: 0.4706 - val_accuracy: 0.8534
Epoch 72/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 297ms/step - loss: 0.1845 - accuracy: 0.9541 - val_loss: 0.4738 - val_accuracy: 0.8434
Epoch 73/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 297ms/step - loss: 0.1838 - accuracy: 0.9528 - val_loss: 0.4703 - val_accuracy: 0.8434
Epoch 74/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 297ms/step - loss: 0.1858 - accuracy: 0.9499 - val_loss: 0.4652 - val_accuracy: 0.8574
Epoch 75/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 296ms/step - loss: 0.1770 - accuracy: 0.9532 - val_loss: 0.4824 - val_accuracy: 0.8454
Epoch 76/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 298ms/step - loss: 0.1724 - accuracy: 0.9536 - val_loss: 0.4806 - val_accuracy: 0.8373
Epoch 77/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 300ms/step - loss: 0.1723 - accuracy: 0.9568 - val_loss: 0.4775 - val_accuracy: 0.8454
Epoch 78/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 300ms/step - loss: 0.1730 - accuracy: 0.9548 - val_loss: 0.4675 - val_accuracy: 0.8494
Epoch 79/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 298ms/step - loss: 0.1690 - accuracy: 0.9548 - val_loss: 0.4611 - val_accuracy: 0.8514
Epoch 80/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 300ms/step - loss: 0.1658 - accuracy: 0.9590 - val_loss: 0.4761 - val_accuracy: 0.8333
Epoch 81/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 299ms/step - loss: 0.1595 - accuracy: 0.9592 - val_loss: 0.4592 - val_accuracy: 0.8534
Epoch 82/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 298ms/step - loss: 0.1636 - accuracy: 0.9603 - val_loss: 0.4642 - val_accuracy: 0.8434
Epoch 83/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 298ms/step - loss: 0.1588 - accuracy: 0.9597 - val_loss: 0.4871 - val_accuracy: 0.8474
Epoch 84/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 297ms/step - loss: 0.1583 - accuracy: 0.9601 - val_loss: 0.4816 - val_accuracy: 0.8373
Epoch 85/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 298ms/step - loss: 0.1602 - accuracy: 0.9588 - val_loss: 0.4701 - val_accuracy: 0.8554
Epoch 86/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 298ms/step - loss: 0.1542 - accuracy: 0.9606 - val_loss: 0.4823 - val_accuracy: 0.8394
Epoch 87/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 296ms/step - loss: 0.1572 - accuracy: 0.9606 - val_loss: 0.4738 - val_accuracy: 0.8373
Epoch 88/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 296ms/step - loss: 0.1498 - accuracy: 0.9637 - val_loss: 0.4739 - val_accuracy: 0.8394
Epoch 89/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 298ms/step - loss: 0.1482 - accuracy: 0.9641 - val_loss: 0.4738 - val_accuracy: 0.8414
Epoch 90/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 298ms/step - loss: 0.1504 - accuracy: 0.9608 - val_loss: 0.4732 - val_accuracy: 0.8353
Epoch 91/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 297ms/step - loss: 0.1474 - accuracy: 0.9634 - val_loss: 0.4780 - val_accuracy: 0.8253
Epoch 92/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 297ms/step - loss: 0.1462 - accuracy: 0.9599 - val_loss: 0.4599 - val_accuracy: 0.8574
Epoch 93/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 298ms/step - loss: 0.1432 - accuracy: 0.9650 - val_loss: 0.4931 - val_accuracy: 0.8434
Epoch 94/100
141/141 [==============================] - 42s 298ms/step - loss: 0.1409 - accuracy: 0.9628 - val_loss: 0.4768 - val_accuracy: 0.8454
Epoch 95/100
141/141 [==============================] - 43s 305ms/step - loss: 0.1405 - accuracy: 0.9699 - val_loss: 0.4650 - val_accuracy: 0.8414
Epoch 96/100
141/141 [==============================] - 43s 308ms/step - loss: 0.1414 - accuracy: 0.9626 - val_loss: 0.4657 - val_accuracy: 0.8313
Epoch 97/100
141/141 [==============================] - 43s 302ms/step - loss: 0.1383 - accuracy: 0.9652 - val_loss: 0.4718 - val_accuracy: 0.8494
Epoch 98/100
141/141 [==============================] - 44s 309ms/step - loss: 0.1365 - accuracy: 0.9659 - val_loss: 0.4669 - val_accuracy: 0.8494
Epoch 99/100
141/141 [==============================] - 44s 310ms/step - loss: 0.1362 - accuracy: 0.9684 - val_loss: 0.4675 - val_accuracy: 0.8434
Epoch 100/100
141/141 [==============================] - 43s 308ms/step - loss: 0.1324 - accuracy: 0.9686 - val_loss: 0.4780 - val_accuracy: 0.8313
```

Accuracy Output:

```
Test Loss: 0.60367
Accuracy on the test set: 82.13%
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can try https://ai.facebook.com/blog/augly-a-new-data-augmentation-library-to-help-build-more-robust-ai-models/

Answer (score 0):

to augment your data set, first you  need to create directories to store the augmented images. Let's name the directory 'aug'. Within aug you need to create a set of sub directories one for each class. Code below will do that

```
aug_path = r'c:\aug' # path to augmentation directory
if os.path.isdir(aug_path):
    shutil.rmtree(aug_path) # remove anything in aug directory if it exists
os.mkdir(aug_path) # make the aug directory
for label in image_df['Label'].unique():
    subpath=os.path.join(aug_path, label) # path for the sub directory
    os.mkdir(subpath)
```

Now the directories have been created to store the augmented images.
Next create and store the augmented images

```
target= 110
image_shape=(256,256)
gen=ImageDataGenerator(horizontal_flip=True, vertical_flip=True, rotation_range=20, width_shift_range=.2,
                              height_shift_range=.2, zoom_range=.2)
groups=image_df.groupby('Label') # group by class
for label in image_df['Label'].unique():  # for every class               
    group=groups.get_group(label)  # a dataframe holding only rows with the specified label 
    sample_count=len(group)   # determine how many samples there are in this class  
    if sample_count< target: # if the class has less than target number of images
        aug_img_count=0
        delta=target-sample_count  # number of augmented images to create
        target_dir=os.path.join(aug_path, label)  # define where to write the images    
        aug_gen=gen.flow_from_dataframe( group,  x_col='Filepath', y_col=None, target_size=image_shape, class_mode=None, batch_size=1,
                                         shuffle=False, save_to_dir=target_dir, save_prefix='aug-',save_format='jpg')
        while aug_img_count<delta:
            images=next(aug_gen)            
            aug_img_count += len(images)
```

now you have created your augmented images and stored them in directory aug.
Now create a dataframe for the augmented images then merge it with the original image_df

```
aug_fpaths=[]
aug_labels=[]
classlist=os.listdir(aug_path)
for klass in classlist:
    classpath=os.path.join(aug_path, klass)     
    flist=os.listdir(classpath)
    print(class_path, len(flist)) # added for your debug    
    for f in flist:        
        fpath=os.path.join(classpath,f)         
        aug_fpaths.append(fpath)
        aug_labels.append(klass)
Fseries=pd.Series(aug_fpaths, name='Filepath')
Lseries=pd.Series(aug_labels, name='Label')
aug_df=pd.concat([Fseries, Lseries], axis=1)
print ('length of aug_df" ', len(aug_df))
print (aug_df.head())
print ('length of original image_df: ', len(image_df))
image_df=pd.concat([image_df,aug_df], axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)
print ('length of augment image_df: ',len(image_df))
```

now image_df will include the original images plus the augmented images.
Notice that image_df is larger than its original size.
Note make sure to shuffle the image_df before you use it for training etc.
The dataset will be balanced as there will be 'target' number of samples
within each class. On an aside you are not using your generators correctly.
You should be putting the augmentations you want within the code for the
ImageDataGenerator, not in the code for flow_from_dataframe. See use of
ImageDataGenerator in the code above.

Comment: Thanks for Your kind contribution, Sir. However, there is nothing generated and İ find an output that is 
`Found 0 validated image filenames belonging to 0 classes.
Found 0 validated image filenames belonging to 0 classes.
Found 0 validated image filenames belonging to 0 classes.
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/dataframe_iterator.py:282: UserWarning: Found 4985 invalid image filename(s) in x_col="Filepath". These filename(s) will be ignored.
  .format(n_invalid, x_col)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist- @GerryP

Comment: packages/keras_preprocessing/image/dataframe_iterator.py:282: UserWarning: Found 4985 invalid image filename(s) in x_col="Filepath". These filename(s) will be ignored.
  .format(n_invalid, x_col)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/dataframe_iterator.py:282: UserWarning: Found 554 invalid image filename(s) in x_col="Filepath". These filename(s) will be ignored.
  .format(n_invalid, x_col)` @GerryP

Comment: On the other hand, we do not define aug_dir. There is another error in line 
classlist=os.listdir(aug_dir)

That is ameError: name 'aug_dir' is not defined @GerryP

Comment: I wrote the code but did not have the time to test it. Let me take a look and I will update it.

Comment: I revised the code and tested it so it should now work

Comment: length of aug_df"  0
Empty DataFrame


Thank YOU however as well as I am having the same error that is 
Columns: [Filepath, Label]
Index: []
length of original image_df:  5539
length of augment image_df:  5539 @GerryP

Comment: Hmm I tested this and I also use this code often so I do not know what might be wrong. I revised the code to add a print statement to help debug. Also look into the aug directory that was created and see if it  has files in it.

Comment: Therefore what should İ have to do now?

Comment: Now İ have been facing the following error in the following line-
`print(class_path, len(flist)) # added for your debug` 
The error
`NameError: name 'class_path' is not defined` @GerryP